# Meteor update array of objects

Tags: meteor

I'm using Schema with this Meteor project. I've got an array of objects in the Schema, which I create them this way:

```
'milestones.$.name'
```

I create some properties like this, and allow for dynamic insert.

Now, I want to grab a milestone by name from milestones array and update some of its properties. 
How can I do this?

I'm trying this at the moment, but still no positive result:

```
Projects.update(
      {_id: currentPostId, 'milestones.name':this.name}, 
      {$set: {'milestones.$': {name: this.name, hours: this.hours, complete:true}}}
    );
```